# Unable to call cURL from perl in Unix

Tags: perl, curl

My project wants to download files on **Unix AIX** from the **AWS** platform. I am trying to call cURL from within Perl script to server this purpose.

I am getting an error

> Can't locate LWP/Curl.pm in @INC. Haven't been able to find libcurl.pm and curl.pm in respective directory of perl installation.

The version of Perl being used here is 5.8.8. I have read about this error and found that it requires `libcurl.pm` (7.10.8 version) and `curl.pm` modules installed in Perl's module library.

Going forward there is a plan to use cURL in combination with FTPS in order to download files from AWS. I have also read WWW library should be used instead of LWP from `cpan.search.org`. Can you advise which is better?

Also, if you could list the prerequisites of using cURL from within Perl script please?

Comment: I think you have too many different questions here...

Comment: Do you have LWP::Curl installed?

Comment: Hi @carlosn, we have not installed LWP::Curl module under perl. We have separately installed cURL on our server.

When I type the below comands I get the following info
`perl -MLWP -le "print(LWP->VERSION)"`
**5.69**

`perldoc -l LWP::Curl`
**No documentation found for "LWP::Curl".**

Comment: If you have curl, you can always shell out and call it directly. But why do you need curl? Can you not work with LWP::UserAgent or Net::FTP (or derivates)?

Comment: Hi @jcaron, sorry just wanted to give a background of what I am trying to do.  <br/>
I am trying to call cURL using perl script and it is not working.  <br/>
We have perl and cURL installed on our server, however would like to know if we need any additional perl modules to use cURL??

Comment: As pointed out by others, you need to have the module installed if you want to use it, though if you want to use curl I would rather recommend the WWW::Curl module. Or indeed the standard LWP which does not use curl.

Comment: LWP != LWP::Curl. `perl -MLWP::Curl -le'print LWP::Curl->VERSION'` and `perldoc -lm LWP::Curl`

Comment: @jcaron: It appears that standard `LWP` doesn't support FTPS.

Comment: @jcaron thank you for your commment and suggestion, I have understood and will get LWP::Curl installed
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

- The `LWP::Curl` module needs to be installed

  It doesn't require `libcurl.pm` or `curl.pm`; indeed, there are no such modules

  It *does* require `WWW::Curl::Easy`, but that will ordinarily be installed automatically when you install `LWP::Curl`
- There are very many `WWW` modules and I can't tell which one you mean

  I would normally recommend the regular `LWP` as it is the "standard" way of writing an internet client, but I don't believe it supports FTPS, so  `LWP::Curl` should do fine
- To install the `LWP::Curl` Perl library, you need to have `libcurl` and the C header files on your system. The `WWW::Curl::Easy` module will build against those, and the build will fail if you don't have them

  That is all you need

You may want to consider `LWP::Protocol::Net::Curl`, which is very similar to `LWP::Curl` but it is a completely separate module by a different author and with different dependencies. It hasn't been updated as recently as `LWP::Curl`, but it is designed and tested as another `LWP:;Protocol` plug-in which can replace the standard protocols leaving  `LWP` to work as normal. `LWP::Curl` doesn't seem to be quite as compatible

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion. Appreciate the detail info you have shared. It is clear now and undesrtood what is missing. I will get the LWP::Curl module installed.
Cheers!